# Merging two dataframes with similar data in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets, df_2010 and df_2013. df_2010 provides data for 2010, while df_2013 provides the same data but updated to 2013 (only df_2010 has columns that are not in df_2013).

```
head(df_2010)
  ID     village surveyor age school salary job_type rich 
1  1         Ara       2   40     5     413        0     1    
2  2       Buxar       1   35     4     618        0     1    
3  3     Sasaram       0   26     5     377        0     1    
4  4   Bodh Gaya       0   19     2     367        0     1    
5  5     Chhapra       3   40     4     265        0     1    
6  6 Muzaffarpur       0   22     3     325        0     1     

head(df_2013)
  ID      village surveyor  salary job_type
1  1         Ara        2 433.6500        0
2  2       Buxar        1 679.8000        1
3  3     Sasaram        0 395.8500        0
4  4   Bodh Gaya        0 359.6600        1
5  5     Chhapra        3 343.7817        1
6  6 Muzaffarpur        0 318.5000        1
```

I'd like to be able to merge and append the two datasets, to be able to compare the changes between 2010 and 2013.

So far, I've created a new dataframe:

```
df_new <- dplyr::full_join(df_2010, df_2013, by == "ID", "village")
head(df_new)
  ID      village surveyor.x age school salary.x job_type.x rich surveyor.y salary.y job_type.y
1  1         Ara         2    40     5       413        0     1         2   433.6500     0
2  2       Buxar         1    35     4       618        0     1         1   679.8000     1
3  3     Sasaram         0    26     5       377        0     1         0   395.8500     0
4  4   Bodh Gaya         0    19     2       367        0     1         0   359.6600     1
5  5     Chhapra         3    40     4       265        0     1         3   343.7817     1
6  6 Muzaffarpur         0    22     3       325        0     1         0   318.5000     1
```

However, I'd like be able to compare any changes between columns.x and columns.y, or any missing values, and then create a single column that merges data for the two dates. Is there any way to do that simply?

Thank you!

Comment: If one of `.x` and `.y` is missing and you want to keep the non-missing one, then `coalesce()` is the function for you. But when they both have values that are different, what do you want to do? *" I'd like be able to compare any changes between columns.x and columns.y,.. and then create a single column"*. How would you loke to compare them? For example, your first row has `salary.x = 413`, and `salary.y = 433.65`? Would you like to sum them? Average them? Always take `.x`? Something else?

Comment: Also, since you mention missing values but your sample data doesn't show any `NA` values, I want to make sure that by "missing" you are using the standard R definition of `NA`, and nothing else. (Some data might have `0` for missing, or `-99` or other unfortunate behavior.)